# How to get the start of line of the current position in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to get the start of the line for the current cursor position on a UITextView

First I get the current position, thats easy.

```
let currentPosition = textView.selectedTextRange!.start
```

Then I should get the startOfLinePosition with this method, but I´m unsure of how to get the offset

```
let startOfLinePosition = textView.positionFromPosition(currentPosition, inDirection: .Left, offset: ?)
```

How can I get the differential offset ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the tokenizer:

```
let currentPosition = textView.selectedTextRange!.start
let startOfLinePosition = textView.tokenizer.positionFromPosition(currentPosition, toBoundary: .Paragraph, inDirection: UITextStorageDirection.Backward.rawValue)!
```

Comment: Works great, but if the line is wrapped it does not work.

Comment: May be you really want the start of the paragraph. Replace `.Line` with `.Paragraph`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.5 version of the answer above:

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = scaledImage
let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
if let currentPosition = textView.selectedTextRange?.start,
   let startOfLinePosition = textView.tokenizer.position(from: currentPosition, toBoundary: .line, inDirection: UITextDirection.storage(.backward)){
    let intPosition = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: startOfLinePosition)
    textView.textStorage.insert(imageString, at: intPosition)
```